# For some of the hive queries I wasn't able to see the o/p?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

My query is

```
SELECT txnno, product FROM txnrecsbycat TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 2 OUT OF 10) ORDER BY txnno;
```

I am getting success but unable to view my O/p
My o/p is:

Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):

```
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
```

In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:

```
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
```

In order to set a constant number of reducers:

```
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>

Starting Job = job_1500975292039_0005, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1500975292039_0005/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1500975292039_0005
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2017-07-25 20:26:48,640 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-07-25 20:27:05,179 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 3.61 sec
2017-07-25 20:27:20,461 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 5.47 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 5 seconds 470 msec
Ended Job = job_1500975292039_0005
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 5.47 sec   HDFS Read: 2498 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 5 seconds 470 msec
OK
Time taken: 51.819 seconds
```

Comment: everything looks good in query. does `select txnno, product FROM txnrecsbycat limit 10` returns anything ?

Answer (score 0):

As OK is there in the output ( which comes before the result), it means nothing was returned from this query. Check the BUCKET data.